# Unable to find maps in tableau

Tags: google-maps, tableau-api

Unable to find map in Sheet after dragging Country / Region into Sheet. there would be some online offline map options which should be explained.

Comment: What do you need help with? What have you tried? Can you provide additional information to help answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that Tableau is recognizing your country field as a country. Click the dropdown on your field to see this:

[image: country role defined]

You should then see the lon/lat(generated) in the col/row as in my image.
If this doesn't work, check the lower right of your sheet for this:

[image: unknown]

If you see this, Tableau isn't able to match your country names to their recognized names. Click the unknown label and you will be able to define the matches.

[image]

You can define the match by searching by country that Tableau recognizes or define it with lat/lon in this screen.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your response, however if i am still not able to see the map in sheet, even upon editing the locations as you have suggested. kindly recheck my updated screenshot and give your opinion https://imgur.com/NZffnSJ